# No overload for 'ConnectWithFacebook_Click' matches delegate 'System.Windows.RoutedEventHandler'

Tags: c#, wpf, facebook, event-handling, facebook-c#-sdk

First of all, I'd like to establish that I'm an extreme n00b at C#, but I'm trying to learn with the help of an intermediate example.

I found this tutorial to create a Facebook application using the FB C# SDK at http://blog.prabir.me/post/Facebook-CSharp-SDK-Writing-your-First-Facebook-Application-v6.aspx. In the tutorial, he has used WinForms, but I wanted to be courageous and made the same program with WPF.

I now face a problem that I see has happened to many users, but I couldn't figure out how I can fix my code. I receive the error as shown below:

```
No overload for 'ConnectWithFacebook_Click' matches delegate 'System.Windows.RoutedEventHandler'
```

I don't get any syntax errors, but when I start the program, this error appears (I think that's what they call a Runtime Error?). As soon as I double click the error, it points to the WPF code.

**Here's my WPF code:**

```
        <Button x:Name="ConnectWithFacebook" Content="Connect with Facebook" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Padding="10, 5"  Margin="520,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="#FF3782DC" Foreground="White" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" FontFamily="Segoe WP N Light" FontSize="14" Height="31" Width="159" Click="ConnectWithFacebook_Click"/>
```

**Here's my C# code:**

```
private void ConnectWithFacebook_Click(FacebookOAuthResult facebookOAuthResult)
    {
        var fbLoginDialog = new FacebookLoginDialog(AppId, ExtendedPermissions);
        fbLoginDialog.ShowDialog();

        DisplayAppropriateMessage(fbLoginDialog.FacebookOAuthResult);

        if (facebookOAuthResult != null)
        {
            if (facebookOAuthResult.IsSuccess)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You have successfully connected you Facebook account!");
            }
        }
    }
```

Please help me overcome this problem, I really hope me and C# can start a beautiful learning experience. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Signature of the ConnectWithFacebook Button  Click Event handler is incorrect.Try this

```
    private void ConnectWithFacebook_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var fbLoginDialog = new FacebookLoginDialog(AppId, ExtendedPermissions);
    fbLoginDialog.ShowDialog();

    DisplayAppropriateMessage(fbLoginDialog.FacebookOAuthResult);

    if (fbLoginDialog.FacebookOAuthResult != null)
    {
        if (fbLoginDialog.FacebookOAuthResult.IsSuccess)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You have successfully connected you Facebook account!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I did try that after taking a look at some of the other questions on SO, but I require the `FacebookOAuthResult facebookOAuthResult` argument as well for use inside the ConnectWithFacebook_Click method. Is there any other way I can reference that?

Comment: create a private field in the same class of type FacebookOAuthResult and assign the value to it . And the you can access its value in this click event handler

Comment: Could you type that up for me? Or tell me where and what to edit? I understood very little from what you just said. Sorry.

Comment: ok no problem but for that i want to know where you getting this value facebookOAuthResult, so that I can assign it accordingly

Comment: I'm getting it from a package I downloaded, the Facebook SDK: `using Facebook;`. The value, I presume, is coming from another window that has been created called `FacebookLoginDialog.xaml.cs` and in that, I found this line `public FacebookOAuthResult FacebookOAuthResult { get; private set; }`

Comment: oh I see if you getting it from FacebookLoginDialog then why dont you directly acces it like fbLoginDialog.FacebookOAuthResult != null.I updated the answer.

Comment: I get 3 more errors now. Since the comments section is a bit messy to type all that, here's a screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/NWkeNYN.png

Comment: as you said FacebookLoginDialog.xaml.cs and in that, I found this line public FacebookOAuthResult FacebookOAuthResult { get; private set; } . but according to errors there is no FacebookOAuthResult property in FacebookLoginDialog.xaml.cs